# Varchar(20 byte) in Oracle synronisation to Mysql varchar(20)?

Tags: mysql, oracle, mariadb

we have Oracle database synchronized to Mysql with Symmetrics. My colleague changed one column to Varchar2(20 byte) in Oracle. I have the same column in Mysql (MariaDB) set to varchar(5). I didn't know about the change in Oracle and the synchronization failed more often than before the change.

Is it possible that this caused the synchronization fail? I have no access to synchronization, so I can only guess.

**The second question is how to change the varchar in MySQL database to fit the change in Oracle? Is it ok to change it to varchar(20) with this command or it needs to be bigger?:**

```
alter table table_name set column col_name varchar (20);
```

(Mysql ver. 15.1. Distrib 10.1.38-MariaDB)

Thank you

Comment: Oracle recommends `varchar2` datatype; probably not related to your question, but - consider that suggestion.

Comment: Hi Littlefoot, I have just read about it on oracle.com, but as I mentioned Oracle is out of my concern. All I need to know is if I can push the data from Oracle's varchar(20byte) to Mysql's varchar(20).

Comment: Unfortunately, I know some Oracle and none MySQL nor MariaDB. Anyway: what was that column's datatype before your colleague modified it? Also, which way does the synchronization happen (I mean, what is *source* and what is *target*)? As of the column size: there is a difference between e.g. varchar2(20 byte) and varchr2(20 char) because of multibyte characters. If you don't expect those, then you won't see any difference, I presume.

Comment: In Oracle it was varchar2(8) and now it's varchar2(20 byte). I found in documentation this: "When declaring a CHAR or VARCHAR type in MySQL, the default length semantics is characters instead of bytes for MySQL 4.1 and later. In Oracle, the default length semantics is bytes for CHAR and VARCHAR2 types and characters for NCHAR and NVARCHAR2 types." If I understand it correctly, considering varchar, byte in Oracle is character in Mysql. Maybe change the length in Mysql to varchar(25) will do the job..

Comment: ..and I edited the question. I added varchar2, because I didn't notice the "2".

Comment: Source of the synchronization is Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY COLUMN ...
              ------
```

In MySQL and MariaDB, `varchar(5)` allows up to 5 *characters*.  If the `CHARACTER SET` is utf8mb4, then that may consume up to 4*5=20 *bytes*.  (I don't know Oracle's interpretation.  Nor do I know anything about Symmetrics.)